# How to make a servlet output several messages progressively

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm using JSP and Servlets to write a Web application. The goal of the app is to provide a simple form in the jsp page, which is used to feed parameters to execute a java program (in the servlet). The output of the program should appear at the bottom of the same jsp page. A lot of sites explain how to to this, however my main issue is that my java program takes several minutes to run, and it prints out a lot of messages before completing. If I simply append those messages to the servlet's HttpServletResponse, then it will wait several minutes before showing all the messages at once. Is there a way to progressively print out the messages on the original jsp page as if it was a java console?

Comment: use ajax...dats the only way..

Comment: you can achieve using `jquery-ajax` post

Comment: Even if you just use ajax to call the servlet, won't it still return the entire results in the ajax response? You may need to have your servlet kick off the program in a separate thread, then setup ajax polling to keep checking the status of the program.

Comment: right dave, the problem persists with ajax...

Comment: thanks to dave's comment, I refined my research and I think the way to do this is by using Asyncronous Servlets. Anyway I don't understand why you downvote the question, it doesn't seem that stupid to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by using ajax.

In ajax call the servlet,then take the necessary informations from the servlet and print it in ajax success part.

[This](http://www.javatutorials.co.in/servlet-3-ajax-hello-world-example-using-jquery/) may help you.

Comment: I used your link by adapting it to my framework (i.e. by forcing some latency between println commands). However the same problem persists: the result is shown only after the program has completely run...

Comment: @splinter123 what problem ?

Comment: the fact that messages are only shown at the end of the program, and not as they are created.

Comment: @splinter123 what do you mean by messages are shown at the end of the program and not as they created? You want to show the output at the bottom of the page,am I right?

Comment: go to the servlet code in your example. After the write command, add a sleep(5000), and then another write command. What will happen is that the two text lines will appear together on the webpage after 5 seconds. What I want is to visualize the first line immediately and the second after 5 seconds, as I would if I was running this as a simple java program.

Comment: @splinter123 yes both the text will print after 5 secs together because you making the thread sleep for 5 secs.you

Comment: yes, just to emulate a time-consuming calculation. Anyway I think I discovered how to do that, by using asyncronous servlets.